# Data vindo errado

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Vi as perguntas semelhantes, porém nenhuma com resposta, a minha data está vindo assim do banco 2017-05-05T00:00:00+00:00 quando eu tento fazer um date('d-m-Y',strtotime($data)); ela vem assim 04-05-2017, tem como fazer ela vir o dia 05-05-2017? Por que isso ocorre? Por que ela volta um dia?

```
echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($publicacao['dataPublicacao']));
```

Aqui pega do banco através do token e id da publicacao e retorna um json

```
  function getSinglePublicacao($id){

session_start();
include_once "token.php";

$token = getToken($_SESSION['username'],$_SESSION['password']);

ob_start();

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://politizar.azurewebsites.net/api/cadastro/publicacao/getSingle/'.$id ); 

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $token ) );

curl_exec( $ch );

$data = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

$httpCode = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );

curl_close( $ch );

    return json_decode($data, true);

}
```

E aqui foi minhas tentativas, obs o retorno de publicacao['dataPublicacao']; retorna  2017-05-05T00:00:00+00:00

```
e o resto retorna a data faltando um dia

$partidos = listarPartido($token_access);

$idPublicacao = $_GET['idPublicacao'];

$publicacao = getSinglePublicacao($idPublicacao);
print_r($publicacao);
$cidades = listarCidades($token_access);

echo str_replace("-","/",date('d-m-Y',strtotime($publicacao['dataPublicacao'])));
echo str_replace("-","/",date('d-m-Y',$publicacao['dataPublicacao']));
echo "<br>";
echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($publicacao['dataPublicacao']));
echo "<br>";
echo $publicacao['dataPublicacao'];
```

Comment: No [Ideone](http://ideone.com/Oe8Bmz) o resultado foi 05-05-2017. Tem certeza que o valor está vindo assim do banco? Qual a versão do PHP?

Comment: A versão é 5.4 e sim está vindo assim do banco @AndersonCarlosWoss será que é algo que fiz errado?

Comment: olha como o Anderson disse: https://ideone.com/Uf7nZ3 não tem como se o valor retornado do banco é assim, e ai não é versão de php talvez seja confusão ou até erro de digitação, dá uma olhadinha melhor!

Comment: E qual é o timezone configurado? Da informação armazenada no banco e no PHP são os mesmos?

Comment: Não sei @AndersonCarlosWoss como coloco a do php igual?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Não... não é erro de digitação pois copiei e colei o retorno aqui... está vindo assim mesmo

Comment: Estranho @AndersonHenrique muito estranho. Acredito não sei posso estar enganado não tem nada a ver com timezone, porque a data não é solicitado ao sistema a data é um valor trazida do banco. Agora fiquei curioso

Comment: Você tem o trecho total desse codigo?

Comment: Tenho sim @VirgilioNovic vou editar a pergunta 1 minuto

Comment: Editado @VirgilioNovic

Answer (score 0):

Olá!!

Me parece haver algo errado com seu código, realizei um teste aqui e passando essa data o valor retorna corretamente.

Tente usar o Datetime. Ex:

```
<?php

$d = new DateTime('2017-05-05T00:00:00+00:00');
echo $d->format('d-m-Y');
```